# Window list ordered by recently used

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, accessibility, macos-carbon

I'm trying to create a window switching application. Is there any way of getting a list of the windows of other applications, ordered by recently used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the [Accessibility framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXIntro). Many of the hooks for screen readers are also useful here. Particularly look at the [UIElementInspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) sample and the [NSAccessiblity protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSAccessibility_Protocol).

There's also [Quartz Window services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Introduction.html), which can easily give you a list of all the windows on screen. Unfortunately, it doesn't tie into concepts like window focus (just level), and I don't know of a way to get notifications back from it when levels change. You might do something like tap into the Quartz Event framework to capture Cmd-Tab and the like, but that's complex and fragile. There is unfortunately [no good way](http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2008/Jan/msg00002.html) to convert a CGWindowID into an AXUIElementRef (the post is for 10.5, but I don't know of anything that was added in 10.6 to improve this). But hopefully you can do everything you need through the Accessibility framework.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use

```
[NSWorkspace runningApplications]
```

to get you a list of all the applications running, and watch

```
[NSRunningApplication currentApplication]
```

to know when the user switches to a new application to keep up with which one is used more recently.